# Appending/Merging 2D Arrays 

Tags: numpy, 2d, append

Is it possible to merge 2D Arrays in Python using numpy or something else ? I have about 200 2D arrays , all with the same Dimensions (1024,256) and want to add them to the lower end of each other. The final shape after adding e.g. 3 of them then should be (1024,768).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three arrays of (1024,256) have to be appended to the *right* end, not the *lower* end. You are stacking them horizontally next to each other (1024 rows, 256 columns).

Using [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) (*h* as horizontal):

`lst` is a list of (numpy or python) arrays `(1024,256)`:

```
numpy.hstack(lst)
```

returns a single numpy array `(1024,256*len(lst))`

Comment: Thanks alot ! I always misunderstood the meaning of horizontal!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple indeed, provided all arrays are the same size.

```
>>> a = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
>>> b = [[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]
>>> c = [a[i]+b[i] for i in xrange(len(a))]
>>> c
[[0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11]]
```

or better

```
sum2darray = lambda a, b:  [a[i]+b[i] for i in xrange(len(a))]
c = sum2darray(a,b)
```

Comment: OP: *I have about **200** 2D arrays*